# To append/insert a large series of numbers using loops in my list upto a particular index?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to append one 1, two 2s, three 3s, four 4s............ upto index 5000.
Please help me.

preview

```
a[1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,6,.............]
```

Comment: What were your attempts? Did you get any errors?

Comment: I was trying to use 2 loops nested but it wasnt working..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
my_list = []
for i in range(5001):
    for x in range(i):
        my_list.append(i)
```

This will work for you

Comment: looks good to me. Suggest inumerate though...

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question correctly, this one-liner should work:

```
[i for l in range(1,5001) for i in l*[l]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
j=0
for i in range(5000):
    j=str(i)
    j=j*i
    print(j)
```

I guess this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Using list comprehension and list flattening,

```python
array = [j for i in range(n + 1) for j in [i] * i]
```

which means

```python
array = []
for i in range(n + 1):
    for j in [i] * i:
        array.append(j)
```

Alternatively, still using list comprehension you could write,

```python
array = [i for i in range(n + 1) for _ in range(i)]
```

In your case, `n = 5000`.